# Root Context/Application Context & Servlet Context

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have been in a bit confusion in understanding the types of context in j2ee.

Please explain Root Context/Application Context & Servlet Context in Spring Web Applications.

i.e. Root Context being created by ContextLoaderListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

APPLICATION CONTEXT / SERVLET CONTEXT

---

**The context created by ContextLoaderListener within a webapplication(i.e. particular WAR) contains singleton beans specific to that *WEB APPLICATION*.**

```
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>

<param-value>/WEB-INF/my-application-servlet.xml</param-value>
```

---

PARENT CONTEXT / ROOT CONTEXT

---

**The context created by locatorFactorySelector or ParentContextKey creates context containing singleton beans for all *WEB APPLICATIONS* within the EAR. (i.e.all WARS within EAR)**

```
<param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>

<param-value>classpath:common-beans.xml</param-value>
```

```
<param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>

<param-value>commonContext</param-value>
```

Answer (score 1):

They are all the same in case of a web application.

- `ServletContext` is something that is available across the web application.
- `applicationContext` variable is available in jsp to access `ServletContext`

Comment: Ok!!
Can you be more elaborative by explaining the below terminology

<context-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEBINF/springconfiguration/applicationContext-web.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>

Comment: @RohitSidhwani, this is hard to read. Please post your code in the question and format properly.

Comment: I have modified my question a little...

Your answer would be valubale.

Comment: The root WebApplicationContext is created by the ContextLoaderListener and contains all of the beans defined in the configuration files referenced by the contextConfigLocation context parameter (unless you NF/applicationContext.xml). By insisting that each DispatcherServlet have its own WebApplicationContext (which extends the global context), Spring encourages encapsulation: beans that are "general purpose" and shared between multiple DispatcherServlets should live in the global context, where as beans that are only interacted with by your DispatcherServlet aren't shared.